# Creating An "Elevated Shortcut" Allowing UAC To Be Bypassed For Certain Trusted Applications?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, uac

The [User Account Control (UAC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) notifies oneself before certain changes are made to your PC ie those which require Administrator level permissions. But sometimes this can be annoying especially for programs that I run frequently and know that I can trust.

Whilst I do not wish to disable the UAC prompt for the whole PC, I would like to run certain programs bypassing the UAC Prompt in Windows by creating an *"elevated shortcut"*.

I also wish to create this elevated program shortcut without the use of [third party applications](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.38) (if possible).

Anyone with experience of creating such a shortcut, would be most appreciated ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Run the task scheduler](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-open-windows-task-scheduler.html), create a task, make sure the checkbox "Run with highest privileges" is enabled, go to the Action tab and select which program you want to run.

Now create a shortcut `C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /RUN /TN "taskname"` and now always use this shortcut to run your application.

I explained this several years ago on [msfn in detail.](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=135472)