# giving permission to program to run with out confirmation in start command windows

Tags: windows-7, command-line, permissions

I am using this

```
start /b C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe
```

command to start a program in my windows( Windows 7 Ultimate - 64 bit).

But then the program want a permission to run

```
Do you want to allow the following program from an unknown publisher make changes to this computer
```

Is there any way to give this permission `as a parameter to the star command` or `using another command`
so that the program start with this permission and don't ask.

Comment: You don't indicate which version of Windows.  There is a well known workaround for Win 7 and Vista (I'm unaware of whether it works in Win 8).  see: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-administrator-mode-shortcuts-without-uac-prompts-in-windows-vista/.  The gist is that you create a task in the Task Scheduler that already has UAC permission, then call that task.

Comment: it is " Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit"

Comment: That workaround should work.  This link describes four different ways to do it: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/task-scheduler-bypass-uac-prompt/

Comment: disabling UAC is a way to stop the confirmation message. Can i do anything without disabling it, like giving permission before asking ?

Comment: That's what the workarounds do.  They provide permission for a single task.  Disabling UAC or reducing its sensitivity is dangerous.

Comment: @fixer1234 can you sum-up the comment as an answer so i can give feed back . Thanks.

Comment: Added some additional solutions in an answer.  Comment if you have problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has actually been discussed in a number of previous SU questions and answers, such as these and others:

- [creating-an-elevated-shortcut-allowing-uac-to-be-bypassed-for-certain-trusted](https://superuser.com/questions/651670/creating-an-elevated-shortcut-allowing-uac-to-be-bypassed-for-certain-trusted)
- [how-to-run-program-from-command-line-with-elevated-rights](https://superuser.com/questions/55809/how-to-run-program-from-command-line-with-elevated-rights)
- [is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows)
- [prevent-elevation-uac-for-an-application-that-doesnt-need-it](https://superuser.com/questions/24631/prevent-elevation-uac-for-an-application-that-doesnt-need-it)
- [how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights)

You generally want to solve the problem in a manner that gives permissions to a specific program rather than reducing the UAC protection in general.  Some of the solutions include:

1. Using a third party utility to create a UAC workaround for the program, such as these and others:

   - [UAC Pass](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/1855/)
   - [UAC Trust Shortcut](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/1857/)
   - [Hidden Start](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html)
   - [ElevatedShortcut](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/1858/)
   - [ShellRunas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361.aspx) from Microsoft
2. Creating a Task Scheduler task with elevated privileges.  This is discussed in several of the above mentioned links and web links with the details are plentiful.  This one shows the procedure in detail: [task-scheduler-bypass-uac-prompt](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/task-scheduler-bypass-uac-prompt/).  The gist of this technique is that you create a task with elevated privileges and then call that task.
3. Invoking a command such as `runas` or `elevate` (may require [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx)).
4. Modifying the characteristics or settings of the program use Microsoft's [Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7352) "to shim the application with the RunAsInvoker fix, which forces the app to run with your standard user tokens". (This one is probably best left for advanced users.)

The Task Scheduler technique doesn't require any other utilities and is pretty straightforward to set up.

Answer (score -1):

This prompt can be ignored by two methods, but reducing UAC sensitivity only. Try this methods and check you outcome.

1. Select the "Change when these notifications appear" link at the bottom of the "Do you want to allow the following program from an unknown publisher to make changes on this computer" window. This way the 'UAC' reduces the sensitivity of the access control of the executable
2. Disabling UAC option. Start > Search box > Action Center > "Change User Access Control Settings" > now, reduce the sensitivity of the access control and check your results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so there is no option without reducing the UAC sensitivity. ?

Comment: Reducing UAC sensitivity exposes you to the risks UAC is there to protect you from.  A better solution is to use one of the methods that just runs a specific program with elevated privileges.

Comment: Yes, you don't have other fix to eliminate the message